# Excel function to calculate unique number for given number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, statistics, excel-2010, excel-2007

can anyone help me here in creating an excel function for unique number to id numbers given.
conditions are:
Reverse the number, subtract 127; divide by 2. I just tried but not able to get that logic.

Comment: What did you try? Please let us know. Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more tips. You, I think, just need an `If` statement.

Comment: Wouldn't this require that the ID numbers already be unique?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ID Numbers begin in `A1`, copy the following formula down for all of your data:

```
=ROUND(((--TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1)*10^(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)))-1)),REPT("0",LEN(A1))))-127)/2,0)
```

[Source](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/488462-formula-reversing-numbers-text.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @radiocontrolled. FYI the given string format will starts with A as A777777.

Comment: they will begin with A but if we want we can only consider the number without A but the output should contain string that starts with A as result.

Comment: @suman Use Find & Replace to remove the "A" from the string.  Then you can use =CONCATENATE to add the "A" back onto the front of the string once you have your desired output.